# Spring - Oauth2 Client server. NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName() While running in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-oauth2

I was trying to develop a client server in oauth2. My resource server and auth server are already in place. To enable the client server as SSO my security config is following

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

    //@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.logout()
                .and()
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                        .getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

For OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter when I include the following in the pom I am getting error when I try to deploy it in a tomcat.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rivigo-oauth-client]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5506)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

Mar 01, 2016 8:42:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /home/rath/work/installations/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/webapps/rivigo-oauth-client.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rivigo-oauth-client]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Including the following dependency in the pom solved the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```